# I cannot run more than 2 containers in Docker

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'm running docker for a project on Github. (https://github.com/mydexchain/mydexchain)

I'm running the code below and creating an image file and a container.

*docker run -d --rm -p 2020:2020 -v mydexchain:/var/lib/postgresql/ --privileged --log-driver=none --name mydexchain mydexchain/mydexchain:latest*

I set my tracker address on port 2020.
I run the container with the attach command. "docker attach mydexchain"

I'm running the code below and creating a second container.

*docker run -d --rm -p 2021:2020 -v mydexchain1:/var/lib/postgresql/ --privileged --log-driver=none --name mydexchain1 mydexchain/mydexchain:latest*

I set my tracker address on port 2021.
I run the container with the attach command. "docker attach mydexchain1"

-So far everything is normal-

I'm running the code below and creating a third container.

*docker run -d --rm -p 2022:2020 -v mydexchain2:/var/lib/postgresql/ --privileged --log-driver=none --name mydexchain2 mydexchain/mydexchain:latest*

I'm checking the containers with the docker ps command.
I see this screen.
[image]

As soon as I want to do anything with this container like attach or set tracker, the container disappears. Like This.

[image]

When I check the logs;

[image]

[image]

When I did these procedures for the first time, I did not encounter any errors.
I would be glad if you could help. I have been working for 1 week and could not find any solution.

Comment: Avoid using `privileged`. This feature should be removed from Docker. It's gigantic security hole.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ensured that all volumes are clean and similar? Usually the path `/var/lib/postgresql/data` is mounted into container.

Might be also related to your pausing/closing your previous `attach` command which kills that container, since you are missing `-i` and `-t` flags when launching the container. Those should be used to prevent it from closing. See more from the documentation of [attach command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/attach/).